# Fixing a particularly obscure Haskell space leak

Tags: haskell, memory-leaks, space

So after having squeezed the last bit of performance out of some Haskell I am using to break tweet data into n-grams, I'm running up against a space leak problem. When I profile, the GC uses about 60-70% of the process and there are significant memory portions dedicated to drag. Hopefully, some Haskell guru will be able to suggest when I'm going wrong.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, BangPatterns #-}
import Data.Maybe
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B
import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict as H
import Text.Regex.Posix
import Data.List
import qualified Data.Char as C

isClassChar a = C.isAlphaNum a || a == ' ' || a == '\'' ||
                a == '-' || a == '#' || a == '@' || a == '%'

cullWord :: B.ByteString -> B.ByteString
cullWord w = B.map C.toLower $ B.filter isClassChar w

procTextN :: Int -> B.ByteString -> [([B.ByteString],Int)]
procTextN n t = H.toList $ foldl' ngram H.empty lines
  where !lines        = B.lines $ cullWord t
        ngram tr line = snd $ foldl' breakdown (base,tr) (B.split ' ' line)
        base          = replicate (n-1) ""

breakdown :: ([B.ByteString], H.HashMap [B.ByteString] Int) -> B.ByteString -> ([B.ByteString],H.HashMap [B.ByteString] Int)
breakdown (st@(s:ss),tree) word =
  newStack `seq` expandedWord `seq` (newStack,expandedWord)
      where newStack     = ss ++ [word]
            expandedWord = updateWord (st ++ [word]) tree

updateWord :: [B.ByteString] -> H.HashMap [B.ByteString] Int -> H.HashMap [B.ByteString] Int
updateWord w h = H.insertWith (+) w 1 h

main = do
  test2 <- B.readFile "canewobble"
  print $ filter (\(a,b) -> b > 100) $ 
     sortBy (\(a,b) (c,d) -> compare d b) $ procTextN 3 test2
```

Comment: Can you provide us with some input data to test with?

Comment: Oh that would help! Here's my test data: https://raw.github.com/esmooov/stash/master/canewobble

Comment: Have you worked out a memory footprint of the data that is going to be in memory? - see Johan Tibell's very useful blog post http://blog.johantibell.com/2011/06/memory-footprints-of-some-common-data.html. In your main routine you are performing a sort - by nature sorts are memory intensive, if you are gathering a of of data sorting it will take a lot of memory.

Comment: @stephen Most of the time is spent in `procTextN`, removing `sortBy` doesn't help much.

Comment: You have really long type declarations so the code doesn't fit very well to the format of a question (and generally look bad). If you import `B.ByteString` and `H.HashMap` unqualified (like this: `import Data.HashMap.Strict(HashMap)` in addition to the qualified import you have now.) that would help a lot.

Comment: @HaskellElephant An easy way to fix this is to use type aliases, like I did [here](https://gist.github.com/1305798).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One small optimisation is to filter the data (using `HashMap.filter`) before sorting it. This helped me shave 2s off the final execution time. Another thing I've done was to use sequences (`Data.Sequence`) instead of lists (no noticeable difference :-( ). My version can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/1305798).

Looking at the heap profile, I don't think that there is a space leak in your program:
[image: Space profile]

You're just building a fairly large hash table (377141 key-value pairs) in memory, and then discard it after some processing. According to [Johan's post](http://blog.johantibell.com/2011/06/memory-footprints-of-some-common-data.html), a hash table of this size takes approx. 5*N + 4*(N-1) words = 3394265*4 bytes ~= 13 MiB, which agrees with what the heap profile shows. The remaining space is taken by the keys and values. On my machine, time spent in GC is around 40%, which doesn't sound unreasonable given that you're constantly updating the hash table and the temporary "stacks", while not doing anything computation-heavy with the data. Since the only operation that you need the hash table for is `insertWith`, perhaps it's better to use a [mutable data structure](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hashtables)?

**Update**: [I've rewritten your program using a mutable hash table.](https://gist.github.com/1305798) Interestingly, the speed difference is not large, but memory usage is slightly better:

[image]

As you can see, the size of the block allocated for the hash table stays constant throughout the execution.

Comment: `Data.Sequence` is generally the preferable data structure any time you need to create a stack.  Lists make particularly poor stacks.

Comment: Yes, but all stacks here are very small (3 elements), so it doesn't matter that much.

Comment: Oh this is an exceptional response. I had some inkling that I might just be paranoid and the issue was, indeed, the large size of the HashMap. I took your suggestion, as per filtering and also - because it's alright if this ngramming is lossy - split the ngramming into 1MB chunks, pruning the HashMap of all small values every round. This is allowing me to now operate on files up to 100MB in < 200MB of memory. Thanks again everybody! (PS: I was considering trying this in a mutable Hash but I always feel guilty using mutable data structures in Haskell. Any psychological advice? Ha!)

Comment: Oh wow, thanks so much for this example for the mutable hash table. This is a great treatment and is interesting to illustrate the performance characteristics of mutable data structures in Haskell. I wrote a parallelized version that was also only marginally faster. Sometimes there's only so much you can do.